# Delete button form tag causes line break

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to have the edit and delete button in the code below side-by-side. They are until i add the `form` tag for the 'delete_dealer_view'. I'm also wondering why I need the `form` can't I just use an anchor tag and call the url? I don't understand what `button` tags are for if I can't surround them with an anchor.

```
<div class="card">
          <div class="card-header card-header-success">
            All Dealers
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table">
              <tbody>
                {% for dealer in dealers %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{dealer.name}}</td>
                  <td class="td-actions text-right">
                    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit Dealer" class="btn btn-white btn-link btn-sm">
                      <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                    </button>
                    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'dealers:delete_dealer_view' dealer.slug %}">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <button type="submit" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-white btn-link btn-sm">
                        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                      </button>
                    </form>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: A GET request is not supposed to have side-effects, so if you would just make a link, then it is not supposed to delete the item, only a POST/DELETE request should do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, Your buttons are not both in the form:

```
<button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit Dealer" class="btn btn-white btn-link btn-sm">
    <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
</button>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'dealers:delete_dealer_view' dealer.slug %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-white btn-link btn-sm">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </button>
</form>
```

Try moving the buttons to both be within the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'dealers:delete_dealer_view' dealer.slug %}">
    <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit Dealer" class="btn btn-white btn-link btn-sm">
        <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
    </button>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-white btn-link btn-sm">
    <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </button>
</form>
```

Might not fix it, but could deffo cause an issue.

Regards,
Josh